# What motherboard should I use for alt coins mining?

Tags: mining-hardware

I want motherboard with 6 PCI-e slot.

Where can I get that?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use this motherboard: http://www.asrock.com/mb/intel/h81%20pro%20btc/

Its one of the most used for mining rigs, since it can hold a lot of gpu's